# Get size for Bytea column in postgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I have table for store file information. File content is stored in column (column datatype is `bytea` in PostgreSQL). Now I want to get file content size, based on bytea column data.

In SQL Server, I am able to get by using below query:

```
select convert(nvarchar(50),DATALENGTH(FileDataInVarbinary)/ 1048576.0 ) +' MB' as FileSize from Table_FileInfo
```

Could you suggest me, how we can write in postgreSQL for same above sql query.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You can use the [`length()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-binarystring.html#FUNCTIONS-BINARYSTRING-OTHER) function to get the length in bytes:

```
select length(bytea_column) as filesize
from file_info;
```

If you want to format the output you can use `pg_size_pretty()`

```
select pg_size_pretty(length(bytea_column)) as filesize
from file_info;
```

That will adapt the "kb", "mb" output based on the size. If you always want MB, you can use:

```
select concat(length(bytea_column) / 1048576.0, ' MB') as filesize
from file_info;
```

Comment: Hello,
Do you convert the result of `length()` in `Mib` ?